# Add Mtext with properties assigned

Tags: lisp, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I'm looking to add mtext in my code, and I'm wondering what the _ calls (I assume) to set things such as Style, color, alignment, Text Height, position etc. to an mtext as I create it. How would I do that amidst something like (command "_.-mtext")?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a command call, use either [`entmake`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-D47983BA-1E5D-417D-85B8-6F3DE5F506BA) or [`entmakex`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-3F9A2EB2-082D-49DD-8EFD-DAD8F6E9AA6A) with an appropriate DXF data list - that way, you can supply the relevant DXF group value for Text Style, Colour, Text Height, Alignment etc. in a single call.

There are hundreds of existing examples demonstrating the use of `entmake`/`entmakex`.

Comment: Thanks Lee, ended up using the following code
(entmake
 (list
  (cons 0 "MTEXT")           ;; Entity Name
  (cons 100 "AcDbEntity")    ;; Subclass Marker
  (cons 410 "Model")         ;; Space
  (cons 8 "TEXT")            ;; Layer
  (cons 100 "AcDbMText")     ;; Subclass Marker
  (cons 10 xyztext)          ;; Insertion Point
  (cons 40 1.6)              ;; Text Height
  (cons 71 3)                ;; Attachment Point (top-left)
  (cons 1 textcontent)       ;; Text Content
  (cons 7 "Arial")))         ;; Text Style

Comment: You're welcome @JesseO'Neill. If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark it as the accepted solution so that the question appears as resolved for others on the site.